# How the Prime number code in python works?

Tags: python

```
def is_prime(num):
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            return False
    return True

def all_primes(num):
    primes = []
    for n in range(2,num+1):
        if is_prime(n) is True:
            primes.append(n)
    return primes

num = int(input("Enter upper limit: "))
primes = all_primes(num)
print(primes)
```

How does it happens... 
What understand is if I enter 10
It will be 10%2= 5...the remainder is 0 so it skip to the next one 9%2 = True there is remainder.

It moves to the next one 9%3 remainder is 0 so it skips to 8% ...,then 7 .......but what I dont understand is 7 if it's check until 7%7 ==0 then how did it add 7 as Prime number???

I'm so confused.

Thank you for any comment

Answer (score 4):

> but what I dont understand is 7 if it's check until 7%7 ==0

The `range` *function* from the following line:

```
for i in range(2, num):
```

goes from `2` to `num - 1`.

So, the `range()` *function* doesn't include the last (stop) number in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong. If you enter `10`, it wouln't check `10%2` and then `9%2`...

It would check `10%2`, then `10%3`, then `10%4`... i.e. it would check `10%i`, for `i` ranging from `2` to `9`. However, note that execution in `is_prime` stops as soon as the remainder is 0:

```
for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            return False
```

So if `num` is `10`, only `10%2` would be checked, and since it's `0`, it would immediately return `false`.

If `num` is `9`, for example, it would check `9%2`. Since the remainder is not `0`, it would move up to checking `9%3`. The remainder is `0` there, so it would return `false` in that case.

If `num` was `7`, it would check `7%2`. The remainder is not `0` so it checks `7%3`, which is also different from `0`, and so on. The last check performed would be `7%6`, because `for i in range(2,num)` means that it will iterate with `i` ranging from `2` to `num-1`. In this case, `is_prime(7)` would return `true` because `7%i`, with `i` ranging from `2` to `6` is different than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

A prime number, by definition, is a number that is divisible only by itself and 1.

Therefore, your function `is_prime` gets the number you want to check if it is prime, and try to find any other number that can divide it inside the interval [2, num), this interval is implemented using the function `range(2,num)` inside the for loop.

If it finds any case, i.e., if the `if (num % i) == 0` is satisfied, we know that there is a number which divides it, therefore, by definition it is not a prime number.
After checking the whole list, if you cannot find a divisor, we can say that the number is prime, i.e., the `return True` on your function.

```
Example:
You want to check 9
(1st step) num = 9, i = 2. 9%2 != 0, we continue in the loop with next value of i.
(2nd step) num = 9, i = 3. 9%3 == 0, we return False. As we know, 9 can divide by 3.

Another example:
You want to check 7
num = 7, i = 2 7%2 != 0, so we continue in the loop with the next value of i
num = 7, i = 3 7%3 != 0, so we continue in the loop with the next value of i
num = 7, i = 4 7%4 != 0, so we continue in the loop with the next value of i
num = 7, i = 5 7%5 != 0, so we continue in the loop with the next value of i
num = 7, i = 6 7%6 != 0, so we continue in the loop with the next value of i

The if was never fulfilled, therefore we reach the end of the loop and 
call the next command, which is return True.
```

Answer (score 0):

when `is_prime` is called for number `7`, the loop will run from `2` to `6` only. Hence `7%7` will never be checked , returning True for such case.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the two function separately:

```
def is_prime(num):
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

This works like this:

- let's consider a number `num`
- get a variable `i` to assume the value `2`
- evaluate the condition `num % i == 0`
- if the condition is met, then exit from the function and return `False`
- otherwise increment `i` by 1 and repeat the last two steps until `i` is equal to `num - 1`
- exit the function and return `True`

So, this never gets to evaluate `7 % 7`: when `num` is `7` the last value of `i` is `6`.

---

```
def all_primes(num):
    primes = []
    for n in range(2,num+1):
        if is_prime(n) is True:
            primes.append(n)
    return primes
```

This gets a number `num` which is the upper limit of the numbers to consider, then:

- it creates an empty `list` named `primes`
- it loops `n` from `2` until `num + 1` excluded (or `num` included)
- if the result of `is_prime(n)` is True, it appends the number to the `list`.
- finally, return the `list` in `primes`.

---

Finally the main body of the script:

```
num = int(input("Enter upper limit: "))
primes = all_primes(num)
print(primes)
```

gets you a string from the keyboard, convert it to `int` and assign to `num`, then call `all_primes(num)` and assign its result to `primes` and print the `list` to screen.

---

So, when you input `10` from the keyboard, it will check the values from `2` to `10` for being prime with `is_prime()`, and not from `10` and reducing them, as you seems to suggest.